# Exclusive/Inclusive DTEND according to RFC5545 and Fullcalendar in event with time part, how to do it right?

Tags: fullcalendar, icalendar, rfc5545, rfc2445

According to [rfc5545](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#section-3.6.1):

> The "DTEND" property for a "VEVENT" calendar component specifies the
> non-inclusive end of the event.

Also in [fullcalendar](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/Event_Object/) documentation for `end` property of event object written the same:

> The exclusive date/time an event ends. Optional.
>
> A Moment-ish input, like an ISO8601 string. Throughout the API this
> will become a real Moment object.
>
> It is the moment immediately after the event has ended. For example,
> if the last full day of an event is Thursday, the exclusive end of the
> event will be 00:00:00 on Friday!

With **allday** event everything is clear, if event from 24/03/2016 to 25/03/2016 I need to write according to described above from 24/03/2016 to 25/03/2016.

Now, my question is how I supposed to write in **DTEND** when event from `24/03/2016 10:00` to `24/03/2016 10:30`, i.e. 30 min event? Do I need to write
`24/03/2016 10:30:01` to create **non-inclusive** end date?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your understanding of the RFC5545 is correct, it is your math which is failing you:

Say you want to have a 1 min event you would have

> DTSTART:20160324T173000Z
>     DTEND:20160324T173100Z

Similarly for a 30 min event you would have:

> DTSTART:20160324T173000Z
>     DTEND:20160324T180000Z