# ICS file when imported in outlook shows wrong end date when no start & end time is specified

Tags: php, icalendar

I have generated ICS file through PHP & JS .

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:https://www.google.com/
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
TZ:+00
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:https://www.google.com/
DTSTAMP:20180308T140833Z
DTSTART;VALUE=DATE:20180308
DTEND;VALUE=DATE:20180312
SUMMARY:"Hamlet"
X-ALT-DESC;FMTTYPE=text/html:<!DOCTYPE HTML><HTML><BODY>Show Times:<br/>March 8-11, 2018 @ 7:30 pm<br/> March 12, 2018 @ 2:00 pm<br/>Often dubbed the “Greatest Play Ever Written” and written by the most produced playwright each year, William Shakespeare, the titular Hamlet.<br/><a href=https://www.whittierevents.com/events/hamlet/>https://www.whittierevents.com/events/hamlet/</a></BODY></HTML>
LOCATION:6760 Painter Ave, Whittier, CA 90601
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

When I import this file in outlook, end date is shown as 11th March though it is 12th March.
How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the spec, the end of an allday event is the beginning of the next day.  So a 1 day event in the ics file will have 2 dates - the DTEND will be the day after the DTSTART.  So in our case, to make it look like it ends on the 12th in applications, the .ics file must say 13th.  See also [Exclusive/Inclusive DTEND according to RFC5545 and Fullcalendar in event with time part, how to do it right?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36206278/exclusive-inclusive-dtend-according-to-rfc5545-and-fullcalendar-in-event-with-ti)